# What makes the require method on the renderer process to be undefined?

Tags: electron

The [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/glossary#renderer-process) still throws an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

even though the [main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/glossary#main-process)' `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` was already set to `true` like so:

```js
function launchMainWindow () {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('main.html')
}
```

This is contradictory to an [answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56342771/1121841). Did I miss something?

What makes the `require()` method on the renderer process to be undefined?

### Warning

- [Enabling `nodeIntegration` has a security risk](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#security-is-everyones-responsibility).
- [Copying code from Stack Overflow? You might paste security vulnerabilities, too](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using the latest Electron version to this date.

In the newest versions of Electron you need to specify both:

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false
}
```

You should add this to all your created Windows to allow the usage of require.

Source: [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I thought I was going crazy it was not working.